# How does the reified keyword in Kotlin work?

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the `reified` keyword. Apparently, [it's allowing us to do reflection on generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html).

However, when I leave it out, it works just as fine. When does this make an actual **difference**?

Comment: Generic type parameters are erased at runtime, read about type erasure if you haven't already. Reified type parameters on inline functions not only inline the method body, but also the **generic type parameter** allowing you do to things like T::class.java (which you can't do with normal generic types). Putting as a comment because I don't have time to flesh out a full answer right now..

Comment: It allows to get access to the concrete generic type of a function without relying on reflection and without having to pass the type as argument.

Comment: You lost me at erasure.  I know it's tradition in kotlin to define keywords via other keywords, but it doesn't help new-comers who don't know what the other words mean either.

Answer (score 857, accepted):

### TL;DR: What is `reified` good for

```
fun <T> myGenericFun(c: Class<T>)
```

In the body of a generic function like `myGenericFun`, you can't access the type `T` because it's **only available at compile time** but [**erased**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) at runtime. Therefore, if you want to use the generic type as a normal class in the function body you need to *explicitly pass the class as a parameter* as shown in `myGenericFun`.

If you create an `inline` function with a **reified** `T`, the type of `T` can be accessed even at runtime, and thus you do not need to pass the `Class<T>` additionally. You can work with `T` as if it was a normal class - e.g. you might want to check whether a variable is an *instance of* `T`, which you can easily do then: `myVar is T`.

Such an `inline` function with `reified` type `T` looks as follows:

```
inline fun <reified T> myGenericFun()
```

---

### How `reified` works

You can only use `reified` in combination with an `inline` function. By doing so, you instruct the compiler to copy the function's bytecode to every spot the function is invoked from (the compiler "inlines" the function). When you call an `inline` function with `reified` type, the compiler has to be able to know the actual type passed as a type argument so that it can modify the generated bytecode to use the corresponding class directly. Therefore a call like `myVar is T` becomes `myVar is String` in the bytecode (if the type argument is `String`).

---

### Example

Let's have a look at an example that shows how helpful `reified` can be.
We want to create an extension function for `String` called `toKotlinObject` that tries to convert a JSON string to a plain Kotlin object with a type specified by the function's generic type `T`. We can use [`com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) for this and the first approach is the following:

**a) First approach without reified type**

```
fun <T> String.toKotlinObject(): T {
      val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
                                                        //does not compile!
      return mapper.readValue(this, T::class.java)
}
```

The `readValue` method takes a type that it is supposed to parse the `JsonObject` to. If we try to get the `Class` of the type parameter `T`, the compiler complains: **"Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead."**

**b) Workaround with explicit `Class` parameter**

```
fun <T: Any> String.toKotlinObject(c: KClass<T>): T {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    return mapper.readValue(this, c.java)
}
```

As a workaround, the `Class` of `T` can be made a method parameter, which then  used as an argument to `readValue`. This works and is a common pattern in generic Java code. It can be called as follows:

```
data class MyJsonType(val name: String)

val json = """{"name":"example"}"""
json.toKotlinObject(MyJsonType::class)
```

**c) The Kotlin way: `reified`**

Using an `inline` function with `reified` type parameter `T` makes it possible to implement the function differently:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> String.toKotlinObject(): T {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    return mapper.readValue(this, T::class.java)
}
```

There’s no need to take the `Class` of `T` additionally, `T` can be used as if it was an ordinary class. For the client the code looks like this:

```
json.toKotlinObject<MyJsonType>()
```

#### Important Note: Working with Java

An inlined function with `reified` type is **not callable from Java** code.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive response! That actually makes sense. Just one thing I'm wondering, why is reified needed if the function is being inlined anyway? It would leave the type erasure and inline the function anyway? This seems kind of a waste to me, if you inline the function you might aswell inline the type being used or am I seeing something wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, actually I forget to mention something which might give you the answer: a normal inline function can be called from *Java* but one with a reified type parameter can't! I think this is a reason why not every type parameter of an inline function is automatically made reified.

Comment: What if the function is a mix of reified and non-reified parameters? That makes it not eligible to be called from Java anyways, why not reify all type parameters automatically? Why does kotlin need to have reified specified for all type parameters explicitly?

Comment: what if upper callers in the stack need not json.toKotlinObject<MyJsonType>(), but json.toKotlinObject<T>() for different objects?

Comment: By the way, I have learnt `ObjectMapper` are expensive to construct so should not construct one new whenever wanting to deserialize *one* object. Thus, is there an approach to make use of `reified` for beautiful code and reuse objectmapper across deserializing? thanks

Comment: When you say "you need to explicitly pass the class as a parameter as shown in myGenericFun"- I don't understand, because the Class<T> is explicit in "Class" (this is a custom class right?), but not explicit in T (the most important part?).

Comment: Actually this becomes virtually self-explanatory when you know what _reify_ means: make (something abstract) more concrete or real. In this case we make the generic parameter _more concrete_. Case solved ;-]

Answer (score 169):

### Understanding `reified` types

**Generics**

While using generics in Kotlin, we can perform operations on a value of any type `T`:

```
fun <T> doSomething(value: T) {
    println("Doing something with value: $value")                 // OK
}
```

Here we are implicitly calling the `toString()` function of the `value` and that works.

But we can't perform any operations on the type `T` directly:

```
fun <T> doSomething(value: T) {
    println("Doing something with type: ${T::class.simpleName}")  // Error
}
```

Let's understand the reason for this error.

**Type erasure**

In the code above, the compiler gives an error: `Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.` This happens because at compile time, the compiler removes the type argument from the function call.

For example, if you call the function as:

```
doSomething<String>("Some String")
```

The compiler removes the type argument part `<String>` and all that's left at the runtime is:

```
doSomething("Some String")
```

This is called *type erasure*. So, at runtime (inside the function definition), we cannot possibly know exactly which type the `T` stands for.

**Java solution**

The solution to this type erasure problem in Java was to pass an additional argument specifying the type with the `Class` (in Java) or `KClass` (in Kotlin):

```
fun <T: Any> doSomething(value: T, type: KClass<T>) {
    println("Doing something with type: ${type.simpleName}")       // OK
}
```

This way our code is not affected by type erasure. But this solution is verbose and not very elegant since we have to declare it as well as call it with an additional argument. Also, specifying the type bound `Any` is mandatory.

**Type reification**

The best solution to the problem above is type reification in Kotlin. The `reified` modifier before the type parameter enables the type information to be retained at runtime:

```
inline fun <reified T> doSomething(value: T) {
    println("Doing something with type: ${T::class.simpleName}")    // OK
}
```

In the code above, thanks to the `reified` type parameter, we no longer get the error while performing an operation on type `T`. Let's see how `inline` functions make this magic possible.

**`inline` functions**

When we mark a function as `inline`, the compiler copies the actual body of that `inline` function wherever that function is called. Since we marked our `doSomething()` function as an `inline`, the following code:

```
fun main() {
    doSomething<String>("Some String")
}
```

gets compiled to:

```
fun main() {
    println("Doing something with type: ${String::class.simpleName}")
}
```

So, the two code snippets shown above are equivalent.

While copying the body of an `inline` function, the compiler also replaces the type parameter `T` with the actual type argument that is specified or inferred in the function call. For example, notice how the type parameter `T` is replaced with the actual type argument `String`.

---

### Type checking and type casting of `reified` types

The main objective of a `reified` type parameter is to know the exact type that the type parameter `T` represents at runtime.

Let's say we have a list of different types of fruits:

```
val fruits = listOf(Apple(), Orange(), Banana(), Orange())
```

And we want to filter all the `Orange` types in a separate list like following:

```
val oranges = listOf(Orange(), Orange())
```

**Without `reified`**

For filtering the fruit types, we may write an extension function on `List<Any>` like following:

```
fun <T> List<Any>.filterFruit(): List<T> {
    return this.filter { it is T }.map { it as T }          // Error and Warning
}
```

In this code, first we filter the types and only take the element if its type matches the given type argument. Then we cast each element to the given type argument and `return` the `List`. But there are two problems.

**Type checking**

While type checking `it is T`, we are introduced to another error by the compiler: `Cannot check for instance of erased type: T`. This is another kind of error you may come across due to type erasure.

**Type casting**

While type casting `it as T`, we are also given a warning: `Unchecked cast: Any to T`. The compiler cannot confirm the type due to type erasure.

**`reified` types to the rescue**

We can easily overcome these two problems by marking the function as `inline` and making the type parameter `reified` as explained earlier:

```
inline fun <reified T> List<Any>.filterFruit(): List<T> {
    return this.filter { it is T }.map { it as T }
}
```

And then call it like following:

```
val oranges = fruits.filterFruit<Orange>()
```

I showed this function for easier demonstration. For the purpose of filtering the types in collections, there is already a standard library function `filterIsInstance()`. This function has used the `inline` and `reified` modifiers in the similar manner. You can simply call it as following:

```
val oranges = fruits.filterIsInstance<Orange>()
```

---

### Passing `reified` parameter as an argument

The `reified` modifier makes it possible for a function to pass the type parameter as a type argument to another function that has `reified` modifier:

```
inline fun <reified T> doSomething() {
    // Passing T as an argument to another function
    doSomethingElse<T>()
}

inline fun <reified T> doSomethingElse() { }
```

---

### Getting the generic type of the `reified` type

Sometimes a type argument can be a generic type. For example, `List<String>` in the function call `doSomething<List<String>>()`. It's possible to know this entire type, thanks to reification:

```
inline fun <reified T> getGenericType() {
    val type: KType = typeOf<T>()
    println(type)
}
```

Here the `typeOf()` is a standard library function. The `println()` function above will print `kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.String>`, if you call the function as `getGenericType<List<String>>()`. The `KType` includes `KClass`, type argument information and nullability information. Once you know the `KType`, you can perform reflection on it.

---

### Java interoperability

The `inline` functions declared without `reified` type parameters can be called from Java as regular Java functions. But the ones declared with the `reified` type parameters are not callable from Java.

Even if you call it using the reflection like following:

```
Method method = YourFilenameKt.class.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething", Object.class);
method.invoke("hello", Object.class);
```

You get the `UnsupportedOperationException: This function has a reified type parameter and thus can only be inlined at compilation time, not called directly.`

---

### Conclusion

In many cases, the `reified` types help us get rid of the following errors and warnings:

1. `Error: Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.`
2. `Error: Cannot check for instance of erased type: T`
3. `Warning: Unchecked cast: SomeType to T`

Comment: this is way more explicit than the accepted answer, thank you!

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank You. But why type is erased?

Comment: @VengateshMurugasamy, if the generic types were to be retained, they would consume a lot of memory and other resources in JVM. So, it was a design decision taken by JVM designers to erase the generic types at runtime. They are useful at compile time for type safety.

Comment: Not sure about other answers are clear enough in explanation. But Im sure I understood reified type after reading the above explanation. Thanks @YogeshUmeshVaity

Comment: Thank you very much for this AMAZING explanation! It is really clear and to the point ;)

Comment: After hours of reading on this topic, finally I have the feeling, that I understand reified type.
Thank you @YogeshUmeshVaity

Answer (score 15):

The purpose of `reified` is to allow the function to use `T` at compile time (to access it within the function).

For example:

```
inline fun <reified T:Any>  String.convertToObject(): T{
    val gson = Gson()
    return gson.fromJson(this,T::class.java)
}
```

To use:

```
val jsonStringResponse = "{"name":"bruno" , "age":"14" , "world":"mars"}"
val userObject = jsonStringResponse.convertToObject<User>()
println(userObject.name)
```