# Kotlin reified type function as function extension - Callable from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I'm trying to use a function with reified type as extension function but I don't think that it's possible because after I checked the generated bytecode I have find that the method signature is private, any work around to make it public ?

**CommonExtensions.kt**

```
inline fun<reified T: Activity> Context.startActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, T:: class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

fun View.visible() {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Kotlin Bytecode :

```
private final static startActivity(Landroid/content/Context;)V
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   ...
```

**Client Code :**

***Kotlin file***

```
override fun showMessageEmptyOfferFeeds() {
        mOfferFeedsWarning.visible() // "visible()" extension func RESOLVED
}
```

***Java file***

```
showProfileDetailsUi(){
   startActivity<DetailActivity>() //"startActivity()" extension func NOT RESOLVED
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use `inline` functions with `reified` types as extension functions. It's made `private` so that **Java** code can't access it (btw this is not the case for "normal" `inline` functions). 
Such an `inline` function can be `private` for **Kotlin** because inline functions are **copied** to the place **where** they are **invoked**.

An [example](https://antonioleiva.com/reified-types-kotlin/):

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Activity.startActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, T::class.java))
}

//usage

startActivity<DetailActivity>()
```

Read more about `reified` in another SO question, I answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/8073652

Once again: *You cannot use `inline` functions with `reified` typed from Java.*

Comment: Yes it's only a class level .. but I can't use it out side the file in which it's defined .. my question is how to use it as normal extension functions ?

Comment: Try to define it top level. That's a class like Extensions.kt which could contain your function only, without a class around it

Comment: Can you share your code? Also where you use it with the compile error?

Comment: Added more details as you asked

Comment: You're trying to call it from Java? This does not work, as I wrote. Make it not reified, normal inline functions are ok for Java!

Answer (score 2):

`inline reified` functions 'disppear' after compilation, because reified types don't exist on the JVM. It is a trick by the compiler.

Probably the only reason the private function is there is to cause an error if someone tries to override it during runtime, since the reified function is completely inlined and cannot be overridden.

Comment: hi, it doesn't disppear. it is only make the visibility to private to avoid java code call it.