# Kotlin: return a generic interface

Tags: generics, kotlin

In Kotlin,  I'm trying to compile the following:

1. given an interface with generic types (Printer)
2. and two implementations of that interface (DogPrinter and CatPrinter)
3. return one of the printers, according to an external variable (AnimalType)

The following code does not compile, because a type is required at:
`fun getMapper(animalType: AnimalType): Printer`

I tried to use `<Any>` or `<*>` but got no success. Can someone help?

*(easy to see the error by copypasting the code below into [https://try.kotlinlang.org)](https://try.kotlinlang.org)_)*

```
enum class AnimalType {
    CAT, DOG
}

class Dog
class Cat

interface Printer<in T> {
    fun mapToString(input: T): String
}


class DogPrinter : Printer<Dog> {
    override fun mapToString(input: Dog): String {
        return "dog"
    }
}

class CatPrinter : Printer<Cat> {
    override fun mapToString(input: Cat): String {
        return "cat"
    }
}

private fun getMapper(animalType: AnimalType): Printer {
    return when(animalType) {
        AnimalType.CAT -> CatPrinter()
        AnimalType.DOG -> DogPrinter()
    }
}

fun usage_does_not_compile() {
    getMapper(AnimalType.DOG)
            .mapToString(5)
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have an enum which seems to do nothing more than mirror the class types? You could simply be passing in the type to getMapper rather than trying to match enums to types.

Comment: it was meant as an example, since in my real case i preferred to have an enum/identifier. But in the end yes, i could pass the type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit. The `getMapper` function is `inline` with a `reified` **generic** type now, which makes the call pretty readable at `getMapper<Dog>()`.

Read about `reified` here: [What does the reified keyword in Kotlin really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949584/what-does-the-reified-keyword-in-kotlin-really-do/45952201#45952201)

```
private inline fun <reified T> getMapper(): Printer<T> {
    when (T::class) {
        Cat::class -> return CatPrinter() as Printer<T>
        Dog::class -> return DogPrinter() as Printer<T>
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(getMapper<Dog>().mapToString(Dog()))
    println(getMapper<Cat>().mapToString(Cat()))
}
```

The reified thing is not even necessary actually but makes the client side more readable. Alternatively, you could also pass in the class as an argument to the `getMapper` function. The really important part is to make this one **generic**.
The unchecked casts are not very cool but seem to be safe here.

Comment: i don't understand why we would need the "as Printer<T>" inside getMapper, but that's ok. Your answer was the best, thanks. I ended up using a solution where i pass in the class type as a getMapper argument. (copied from your link)

Comment: In the end this looks like an example for "How to break type safety?".

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin doesn't have raw types so you can't return `Printer` from `getMapper`. You can either return `Printer<*>`, make `getMapper` generic, or change your inheritance structure to have a common super type.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `Printer<*>` works fine. But it isn't actually useful because you can't call `mapToString(Dog())` (I assume `mapToString(5)` is a typo) and it's a good thing: if it compiled then

```
getMapper(AnimalType.CAT).mapToString(Dog())
```

would also have to compile, because the return *type* can only depend on argument *type*, not on *value*, and `AnimalType.CAT` and `AnimalType.DOG` have the same type. There are some languages which allow it, but Kotlin isn't one of them.

Comment: yes, mapToString(5) was a typo. Anyway, i had to fight with the compiler to understand the error messages but now that you say that, it makes sense. thanks for your answer.