# How to check a generic type inside a Kotlin function?

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I am using Kotlin to parse JSON. For example, I have this representation of a country: `{"code":"US", "name":"United States of America"}`. To produce a `Country` object from such a `JSONObject`, I have this function:

```
val produceCountry = fun (js: JSONObject) =
        Country(js.getString("code"), js.getString("name"))
```

I can easily parse an array of `Country` with this function. Besides arrays of `Country`, however, I also have arrays of `Cat`, `Car`, `Cart`, `CordlessPhone`, etc. Each has their own `produce*` function transforming a `JSONObject` to a Kotlin object of that type. To generalize array parsing, I have this function:

```
fun <T> produceSetOf(array: JSONArray, element: (JSONObject) -> T): Set<T> {
    val set = mutableSetOf<T>()

    for (i in 0 until array.length())
        set.add(element(array.getJSONObject(i)))

    return set
}
```

So I can call `produceSetOf(jsonArray, produceCountry)` on encountering an array whose elements are of type `Country`. This works well on arrays of `Cat`, `Car`, `Cart`, `CordlessPhone` too.

Problem arises when I see an array of strings. Instead of `array.getJSONObject(i)`, I have to use `array.getString(i)`. In effect, I am thinking of introducing another parameterized type to the function above and have it make the call differently:

```
fun <S,T> produceSetOf(array: JSONArray, element: (S) -> T): Set<T> {
    val set = mutableSetOf<T>()

    for (i in 0 until array.length()) {
        when (S) {
            is String -> 
                set.add(element(array.getString(i)))
            is JSONObject ->
                set.add(element(array.getJSONObject(i)))
        }
    }

    return set
}
```

Of course, **Kotlin does not allow me to do that**. Any suggestion how I could do that while maintaining the generality of `produceSetOf()` and without introducing another layer of abstraction (e.g. an element iterator, or a function transforming an index into String/JSONObject)?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use reifeid type parameters for this. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters . In your case I would add the `inline` and `reified` keywords and then check for `S::class` in your when.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/5335131

Comment: @AndreasVolkmann, thank you. `inline` and `reified` do the job, EXCEPT that it now complains (at `is String`) about `Incompatible types: String and KClass<S>`. If I put `S::class.java` in `when`, the complaint turns to `Incompatible types: String and Class<S>`. The line `is JSONObject` does not raise complaint in either case. Any clue why that is? Thank again.

Comment: Use `when (S::class) ` `String::class` instead of `is String`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one possible solution using reified type parameters.

```
inline fun <reified S, T> produceSetOf(array: JsonArray, element: (S) -> T): Set<T> {
    val set = mutableSetOf<T>()

    for (i in 0 until array.size()) {
        when (S::class) {
            String::class -> set.add(element(array[i].string as S))
            JsonObject::class -> set.add(element(array[i].obj as S))
        }
    }

    return set
}

val stringArray = listOf("1", "2").toJsonArray()

val stringSet = produceSetOf<String, Int>(stringArray) { it.toInt() }
println(stringSet) // prints [1, 2]

val objArray = listOf(jsonObject("key" to "value"), jsonObject("key" to "other")).toJsonArray()
val objSet = produceSetOf<JsonObject, String>(objArray) { it["key"].string }
println(objSet) // print [value, other]
```

I used gson for the Json objects, since I didn't know where yours were from.

A possible shorter solution:

```
inline fun <reified S, T> produceSetOf(array: JsonArray, element: (S) -> T): Set<T> = array.map {
    when (S::class) {
        String::class -> element(it.string as S)
        JsonObject::class -> element(it.obj as S)
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("${S::class.simpleName} is not supported")
    }
}.toSet()
```