# Casting response to return moddel using Generic type to deserialise api response

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting, okhttp, json-deserialization

I have an API that returns a wrapped result and I want to make one generic wrapper instead of 20.

However I can't get the result value to be cast to my generic type.
This is the code:

On response  from api:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

        val userResponse = response.getResultAs<UserResponse>()

        userResponse?.let { user ->
            App.shared.userSettings.edit().putString(UserSettingsKeys.ACTIVE_USER.key,
                    ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user)).apply()
            App.shared.userSettings.edit().putString(UserSettingsKeys.TOKEN.key,
                    response.header("Authorization")).apply()
            presenter?.onLoginSuccess(user)
        } ?: presenter?.onLoginFailure("No response returned")
}
```

Extension for the result class:

```
fun <T> Response.getResultAs(): T? {

    this.body()?.string()?.let {
        val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
        val obj = JsonParser().parse(it).asJsonObject.toString()
        val baseResponseWrapper: BaseResponseWrapper<T> = mapper.readValue(obj)

        when {
            baseResponseWrapper.errorValues != null -> {
                baseResponseWrapper.logErrorMessage = "invalid credentials"
            }

            baseResponseWrapper.returnVal == null -> {
                baseResponseWrapper.logErrorMessage = "returnVal could not be parsed"
            }

            else -> {
                return baseResponseWrapper.returnVal
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Response wrapper class:

```
data class BaseResponseWrapper<T>(

    @field:JsonProperty("returnVal")
    val returnVal: T? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("errorDescription")
    val errorDescription: String? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("errorCode")
    val errorCode: Int? = null,

    @field:JsonProperty("errorValues")
    val errorValues: Any? = null,

    var logErrorMessage: String? = null

)
```

It parses the data into a correctly formated Linked Hash map, not as my class.
This is my state just before it crashes in debug:

```
baseResponseWrapper.returnVal = {LinkedHashMap@7400}  size = 9  
0 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7409} "isInfluencer" -> "false"  
1 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7410} "currentUserBranchUsername" -> "000"  
2 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7411} "parentUser" -> " size = 4"  
3 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7412} "profile" -> " size = 3"  
4 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7413} "currentUserProfile" -> "null"  
5 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7414} "email" -> "null"  
6 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7415} "userName" -> "null"  
7 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7416} "muviId" -> "null"  
8 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry@7417} "userId" -> "0000-0000-0000"
```

and this is my console error:

> 2018-10-29 12:56:15.401 1916-1962/com.appshack.livetree
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
>       Process: com.appshack.livetree, PID: 1916
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
>           at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:408)
>           at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:402)
>           at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:469)
>           at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:175)
>           at com.appshack.livetree.utililty.extensions.OkHttpResult_getResultAsKt.getResultAs(OkHttpResult+getResultAs.kt:17)
>           at com.appshack.livetree.ui.outside.login.LoginInteractor$loginResponseCallback$1.onResponse(LoginInteractor.kt:43)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
>           at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Im new to generics but is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: You need https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430704/3496570

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/3496570

Comment: Thank you!
Nice timing since I just came back to this project.

Comment: Answer your own question if you are succeeded

Comment: I will, but for now it's in my backlog due to more pressing issues.