# Calling a fun with reified type parameter if you just have a KClass object?

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

One can only use reified type parameters with inline functions. So if I want such a parameter for a class I need a trick like this:

```
class Foo<T : Any>(private val clazz: KClass<T>) {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T: Any> create() = Foo(T::class)
    }
}
```

I can then create instances of `Foo` like this:

```
val foo = Foo.create<Bar>()
```

Within `Foo` I have access `clazz` but my question is **can I then use `clazz` when I need to call methods that require a reified type parameter`**?

E.g. within `Foo` I'd like to add a method like this:

```
fun print(list: List<Alpha>) {
    list.filterIsInstance<T>().forEach { print(it) }
}
```

But as far as I can see there's no way to get from `clazz` to something I can use as a type parameter here.

And yes, I know there's a form of `filterIsInstance` that takes a `Class` so I can do:

```
list.filterIsInstance(clazz.java).forEach { print(it) }
```

However many libraries contain methods where both forms (explicit class parameter and reified type parameter) are *not* provided.

E.g. the Jackson Kotlin [Extensions.kt](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/kotlin/Extensions.kt). Actually this isn't a great example as the non-reified equivalents are all one-liners but this isn't always the case - then you end up unpacking the implementation of the reified-type-parameter method into your code.

Comment: Given the description of how reification works in this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201) it seems clear anything to do with `reified` is resolved at _compile_ time so you cannot hope to do anything with a `KClass` or `Class` object that you've acquired at runtime (all methods involving `reified` have been inlined at this point and essentially don't exist in any real sense at runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, because those functions are `inline`, they are inlined at compiletime
and a Class or KClass is using reflection at runtime

there are some tricks that you can do.. like with the companion class, but that does nto need the `KClass<T>` at all.. anything else that provides a generic argument of `T` would work just as well for the `reified` type info

PS: reflection also cannot help you reliably because inline functions do not really exist at runtime, as explained by their modifier `inline`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, everything you can do with `T` in a function with `reified T` *can* be translated to a use of `KClass`: e.g. `x is T` becomes `clazz.isInstance(x)`, `x as T` becomes `clazz.cast(x)`, calls of other functions with reified type parameters are translated recursively, etc. Since the function has to be inline, all APIs it uses are visible at the call site so the translation can be made there.

But there's no automatic way to do this translation, as far as I know.