# BaseFragment architecture for android project

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am starting on a new project and I will be working in a team of 10 developers. I am setting up the base structure for our Android app. As I am working with a team and I want everyone to follow the same structure i.e creating `ViewModel` for each `fragment` and use data binding. How can I make it strict so that developers get an error if they don't create `ViewModel` for their Fragment?

So I have created the below `BaseFragment`:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<out VM : BaseViewModel, DB : ViewDataBinding> : Fragment() {

    open lateinit var binding: DB

    private fun init(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, getLayoutRes(), container, false)
    }

    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun getLayoutRes(): Int

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        init(inflater, container)
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        return binding.root
    }

    open fun refresh() {}
}
```

How can I improve it more?

Comment: I would also add mandatory super call to `onCreateView()` using `@CallSuper` so they stick to not override base behavior.

Comment: Any specific implementation you have @NikolaDespotoski ?

Comment: There is no guarantee that 1 Fragment will use 1 specific ViewModel. Sometimes you don't need ViewModel and sometimes you need 2+. Adding it as a template to the fragment itself is a mistake that leads to coupled code and will cause problems later on.

Answer (score -1):

One of the possible ways to improve your base fragment is to use `reified` like this:

```
protected inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> getViewModel(): T =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[T::class.java]
```

and call is:

```
private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = getViewModel()
```

Useful links on this approach:http://www.albertgao.xyz/2018/05/22/3-ways-to-handle-view-model-creation-in-android-with-dagger-and-kotlin/

[How does the reified keyword in Kotlin work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949584/how-does-the-reified-keyword-in-kotlin-work/45952201#45952201)

https://proandroiddev.com/how-reified-type-makes-kotlin-so-much-better-7ae539ed0304

Comment: With this approach, you lose the ability to use `ViewModelProvider.Factory`. I'm sure you can improve it with some optional method parameters and default values.