# How to make jackson accept generic on readvalue?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I'm doing some refactoring in a awful code because I have functions that are very similar:

```
    fun getLogin(username: String) {
        val uri = buildURI(BASE_URI, ApiRoute.GET_LOGIN.route, username)
        val httpResponse = execRequest(uri, HttpMethod.GET)
        val login: LoginResponse = mapper.readValue(httpResponse)

    fun getUser(username: String) {
        val uri = buildURI(BASE_URI, ApiRoute.GET_LOGIN.route, username)
        val httpResponse = execRequest(uri, HttpMethod.GET)
        val login: userResponse = mapper.readValue(httpResponse)
```

The only difference between those lines is the return type of call `mapper.readValue(httpResponse)`. Based on that, I have wrote a new function to be used in both scenarios:

```
    fun <T> getEvent(value: String, eventType: EventType): T {
        val uri = buildURI(BASE_URI, eventType.route, value)
        val httpResponse = execRequest(uri, HttpMethod.GET)

        return mapper.readValue(httpResponse);
    }
```

The problem is: I cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. How can I wrote a function that pass a "generic" value to jackson?

Answer (score 1):

Generic type is loss at runtime due to type erasure. This is why you can't use `T` with `readValue`, because `T` is used only to ensure compile time type safety, but doesn't exist at runtime.

To solve this, you can make your function `inline` and the generic type parameter `reified`, so the type class will be obtained at the call site:

```
inline fun <reified T> test(value: String): T {
    return mapper.readValue(value, T::class.java)
}
```

Or if you use the Jackson Kotlin module:

```
inline fun <reified T> test(value: String): T {
    return mapper.readValue<T>(value)
}
```

I simplified your use case a little, but it's works the same.

Further reading:

- [How does the reified keyword in Kotlin work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/5288316)
- [Inline Functions and Reified Type Parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters)