# About generics causing ClassCastException LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to Any

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Kotlin Code

```
class ResponseBody<T> {
    var code : Int = 0
    var msg : String = ""
    var data : T? = null
}

class ExampleT {
    var text: String = ""
    // var list: List<String>? = null
}

// utils fun
fun <T> request(json : String) : ResponseBody<T>? {
    val gson = Gson()
    var responseBody: ResponseBody<T>? = null
    if (json.contains("code") && json.contains("data")) {         
         responseBody = gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<ResponseBody<T>>() {}.type)
    } else {
         val tdata : T = gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
         responseBody = ResponseBody()
         responseBody.code = 200
         responseBody.msg = "success"
         responseBody.data = tdata
    }
    return responseBody
}

// main
val json : String = "{\"code\":200,\"msg\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"text\":\"text text text\"}}"
// val json : String = "{\"text\":\"text text text\"}"
val responseBody : ResponseBody<ExampleT> = request(json)
```

result error

```
ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to ExampleT
```

How can I modify my code to fix this?

Comment: Try this: https://pl.kotl.in/HQ9Mxvl9C

Comment: the code does not compile, the last line needs to be: `val responseBody : ResponseBody<ExampleT>? = request(json)` (added `?` to type)

Comment: Except for the compile error, the code actually runs as is. Cannot reproduce your problem (using Gson 2.8.0)

Comment: Thanks everyone, @JeneaVranceanu ‘s answer saved me.

Comment: @ChaoYang, if you do not mind I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: @ChaoYang Can you confirm that the given exception was thrown with the code you posted? For me the given code worked without any problems.

Comment: @WilliMentzel I use Gson version 2.8.6, no matter it is Java or Kotlin, the same error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears from OP response in question's comment section using `reified` helped to solve the problem. Original source code had to be modified in order to make use of `reified` keyword. Functions are inlined and extension function for Gson is implemented to avoid the use of `TypeToken` class.

Here is great SO answer: [What is `reified`, how it works and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949584/how-does-the-reified-keyword-in-kotlin-work)

```
class ResponseBody<T> {
    var code : Int = 0
    var msg : String = ""
    var data : T? = null
}

class ExampleT {
    var text: String = ""
    // var list: List<String>? = null
}

// utils fun
inline fun <reified T> request(json : String) : ResponseBody<T> {
    val gson = Gson()
    var responseBody: ResponseBody<T>? = null
    if (json.contains("code") && json.contains("data")) {
        return gson.fromJson(json)
    } else {
        val tdata : T = gson.fromJson(json)
        responseBody = ResponseBody()
        responseBody.code = 200
        responseBody.msg = "success"
        responseBody.data = tdata
    }
    return responseBody
}

inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String): T {
    return fromJson(json, T::class.java)
}

// main
val json : String = "{\"code\":200,\"msg\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"text\":\"text text text\"}}"
// val json : String = "{\"text\":\"text text text\"}"
val responseBody : ResponseBody<ExampleT> = request(json)
```

Comment: Could you reproduced the error of the OP? I couldn't. Actually, `reified` shouldn't be needed here since OP's code does not access the type.

Comment: @WilliMentzel, no I actually could not reproduce the issue. Probably it could be the issue related to a specific version of Gson library (or maybe the issue was in some other place and the question's content is incorrect). What I did is just replaced `TypeToken` with inlined function with reified generic type as they both deal with type erasure. It was easy to send an example and since OP commented on that solution as helpful I decided to post it as an answer.

Comment: "it could be the issue related to a specific version of Gson library (or maybe the issue was in some other place and the question's content is incorrect)" true, but I think using a reified type is better in the end than to use `TypeToken`. So good idea! it is just unfortunate that the problem can't be reproduced with what is given in the question. :(