# Compile error with Kotlin generics and sealed interface

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a question regarding Kotlin and generics. I have a compile error, that I don't understand. I have a very simplified example below. Since Kotlin data classes can't inherit from other data classes, I've done a lot of my class design with composition. That leads to nested data classes. At some points I use generics to switch the type for parameters I can pass into an object.
I need to modify values of these data classes and because they are immutable, I use the copy function and put that stuff into a Mutator class.

```
class Mutator<out P : Params>(val form: Form<P>) {
    fun modifyName(name: String): Form<P> =
        when (form.params) {
            is DefaultParams -> form.copy(params = form.params.copy(name = name)) // compile error
            is ExtendedParams -> form.copy(params = form.params.copy(name = name)) // compile error
            else -> form // also.. why do I need that.. Params is sealed..
        }
}

sealed interface Params

data class DefaultParams(val name: String) : Params
data class ExtendedParams(val name: String, val age: Int) : Params

data class Form<out P : Params>(val params: P)

fun main() {
    val form: Form<DefaultParams> = Form(DefaultParams("John"))
    val mutator: Mutator<DefaultParams> = Mutator(form)
    val newForm: Form<DefaultParams> = mutator.modifyName("Joe")

    val next_form: Form<ExtendedParams> = Form(ExtendedParams("John", 30))
    val next_mutator: Mutator<ExtendedParams> = Mutator(next_form)
    val next_newForm: Form<ExtendedParams> = next_mutator.modifyName("Joe")
}
```

I get errors on the first two branches of the when block.

> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> P
> Found:
> DefaultParams

> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> P
> Found:
> ExtendedParams

Shouldn't `Params` be the upper bound of `P` and thus fine to find `DefaultParams` or `ExtendedParams`?
And also `Params` should be sealed, but I need an else block in the when.

Comment: It's a known limitation of Kotlin smart-casting. Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32574

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you just use an unchecked cast here:

```
is DefaultParams -> form.copy(params = form.params.copy(name = name) as P)
is ExtendedParams -> form.copy(params = form.params.copy(name = name) as P)
```

Note that this unchecked cast is very safe, because of the semantics of the [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) method. `copy` does not change the runtime type of its receiver. Therefore, it is no more unsafe to pass the *copied* `form.params` than to pass the original `form.params`. And the compiler allows you to pass the original `form.params` here. The compiler is just not smart enough to work out that since `form.params` is a specific `Params`, `P` must be that specific `Params` too.

The `when` statement is not exhaustive because the type of `form.params` is not `Params`, but `P`. (Yes, the compiler is quite stupid sometimes). According to the [spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#exhaustive-when-expressions), a condition for an exhaustive `when` expression is:

> The bound expression is of a sealed class or interface

Note that it doesn't say "a type parameter bounded to a sealed class or interface". So if you just add `as Params`, it will become exhaustive:

```
fun modifyName(name: String): Form<P> =
    (form.params as Params).let { formParams ->
        when (formParams) {
            is DefaultParams -> form.copy(params = formParams.copy(name = name) as P)
            is ExtendedParams -> form.copy(params = formParams.copy(name = name) as P)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly myself why it is the case, but I think it's something to do with P being a generic. Because if you rewrite the Mutator as this you can leave out the else and there's also no error.

```
class Mutator(val form: Form<Params>) {
    fun modifyName(name: String): Form<Params> =
        when (form.params) {
            is DefaultParams -> form.copy(params = form.params.copy(name = name)) // compile error
            is ExtendedParams -> form.copy(params = form.params.copy(name = name)) // compile error
        }
}
```

In fact, I think for your use case you don't need generics and this solution might be exactly what you need.

EDIT:

if you modify it to this

```
class Mutator<out P : Params>(val form: Form<P>) {
    fun modifyName(name: String): Form<P> =
        when (form.params) {
            is DefaultParams -> form.copy(params = (form.params.copy(name = name) as P))
            is ExtendedParams -> form.copy(params = (form.params.copy(name = name) as P))
            else -> form
        }
}
```

it should work like you wanted. It will no longer have a compiler error. It will give a warning though that `as P` is an unchecked cast. But for us it's easy to see that this never will be a problem. I guess the compiler is just not smart enough.

Comment: Problem with that solution is, that the method returns Form<Params> and not the specialized type. I think I need to cast then, which makes it kind of unsecure?

Comment: @Irxw hmm, not sure about it being insecure, but yeah you got a point that it won't be the specialized type. Not sure how you could improve it

Comment: @Irxw see my edit. It maybe is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the parameters to `P` because that is what the compiler expects for the `copy` function. However, this gives you a warning about an unchecked cast exception (which is relatively safe, see [Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69807289/6629569)).

In case you'd like to avoid this Exception, you can turn the `modifyName` into inline function instead and use reified parameters (see the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unchecked-casts) on unchecked casts, and this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/6629569) on the reified keyword).

```kotlin
inline fun<reified P: Params> Form<P>.modifyName(name: String): Form<P> =
    when (this.params) {
        is DefaultParams -> copy(params = params.copy(name = name) as P)
        is ExtendedParams -> copy(params = params.copy(name = name) as P)
        else -> this
    }

sealed interface Params

data class DefaultParams(val name: String) : Params
data class ExtendedParams(val name: String, val age: Int) : Params

data class Form<out P : Params>(val params: P)

fun main() {
    val form: Form<DefaultParams> = Form(DefaultParams("John"))
    val newForm: Form<DefaultParams> = form.modifyName("Joe")

    val nextForm: Form<ExtendedParams> = Form(ExtendedParams("John", 30))
    val nextNewForm: Form<ExtendedParams> = nextForm.modifyName("Joe")
}
```

This will inline the types in the generated bytecode, so that when you call `form.modifyName("Joe")` in the above example, the function `modifyName` will know that `P` is `DefaultParams`, and thus you can return an instance of `Form<DefaultParams>` (instead of `Form<Params>`).