# Why is overloading not working for this case in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, why is it not able to pick from these functions based on the return type of the suspend function? Apart from providing different function names, which I really don't want to do, what are the alternatives?

```
@JvmName("hasPermission1")
suspend fun <T> hasPermission(requiredPermissions: String, block: suspend () -> T): DataFetcherResult<T> {
    println("todo check permissions: $requiredPermissions")
    return failureResult(
        Unauthorized()
    )
}

suspend fun <T> hasPermission(requiredPermissions: String, block: suspend () -> DataFetcherResult<T>): DataFetcherResult<T> {
    return failureResult(
        Unauthorized()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `block` lambda parameter will be converted into `Function` class. If you look at the error given by the Android Studio, it said that both function has same JVM signature
`hasPermission(Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;)`

This is your `block` parameter

`Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1`

You can also check it by showing the kotlin bytecode

Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode

Answer (score 0):

**Because they have the same signature.**

The description of the first block: `() -> T` is so similar to the second `() -> DataFetcherResult<T>`, it can't be distiguished.
In short: `T` can literally be `DataFetcherResult` and the compiler is confused.

**Alternative**:

Using `inline` and `reified` to read the class type inside and decide accordingly:

```kotlin
suspend inline fun <reified T> hasPermission(requiredPermissions: String, block: suspend () -> T): DataFetcherResult<T> {
    return when(T::class) {
            DataFetcherResult::class -> TODO("DataFetcherResult stuff")
            else -> TODO("Other stuff")
        }
}
```

More info on what reified means and how to use it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/12141859)