# Difference between 'Reified' and 'Any' types in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some confusion about the differences in between **reified** and **any** types in Kotlin.

I have some info about the meaning of the keyword but not sure at which cases we can choose the refined? and which case to use any?

Can any one help me to specific answer on that?

Comment: Do you mean `reified` instead of refined?

Comment: If you mean `reified`, that is a keyword. `Any` is a class. They are two entirely different things. The latter is the root of the Kotlin class hierarchy (like `Object` in Java). For the former, check out [How does the reified keyword in Kotlin work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45949584/6395627).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reified keyword in Kotlin**

To access the information about the type of class, we use a keyword called reified in Kotlin. In order to use the reified type, we need to use the inline function .

> If a function is marked as inline , then wherever the function is
> called, the compiler will paste the whole body of the function there.

**Example**

```
inline fun <reified T> genericsExample(value: T) {
    println(value)
    println("Type of T: ${T::class.java}")
}
fun main() {
    genericsExample<String>("Learning Generics!")
    genericsExample<Int>(100)
}
```

**Any**

Object is the root of the class hierarchy in Java, every class has Object as a superclass. In Kotlin theAny type represents the super type of all non-nullable types.

*It differs to Java’s Object in 2 main things:*

> - In Java, primitives types aren’t type of the hierarchy and you need to box them implicitly, while in Kotlin Any is a super type of all
>   types.
> - Any can’t hold the null value, if you need null to be part of your variable you can use the type Any?

java.lang.Object methods toString, equals and hasCode are inherited fromAny while to usewait and notify you will need to cast your variable to Object to use them.

**Example**

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.any(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    if (this is Collection && isEmpty()) return false
    for (element in this) if (predicate(element)) return true
    return false
}

public inline fun <T> Sequence<T>.any(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    for (element in this) if (predicate(element)) return true
    return false
}
```