# Why do Kotlin/Java functions look so different in real use from documentation?

Tags: kotlin

For example here is `all()` in action:

```
fun Shop.checkAllCustomersAreFrom(city: City): Boolean =
    customers.all { it.city == city }
```

And here is the equivalent from the [kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html):

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.all(
    predicate: (T) -> Boolean
): Boolean
```

Can someone please explain each part of the second code block and why it's written like that?

Apologies if this is a basic question, but if I learn this it will be much easier to read documentation.

Comment: Read [Kotlin Extension Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

Comment: I have and I didn't find it very clear - I'd prefer to have SO users try explain it to hopefully give a more concise answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down, shall we?

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.all(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean
|--1--|-2-|-3-|-----4-----|-5-|----6-----|------7-------|----8----|
```

1. This function is [inline](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions). This means that [its body essentially gets copy-pasted to the call site at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44471411/4465208), as an optimization measure (used in this case because it has a lambda parameter).
2. Declares a function.
3. Type parameter list, this function has one generic type parameter called `T`.
4. This is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions), and this is its receiver, i.e. the type being extended. This function will be callable on any `Iterable<T>` as if it was a member function. The `Iterable` that it was called on can be accessed inside the function's body as `this`.
5. The name of the function.
6. The name of the first and only parameter of the function (if we don't count the receiver, which is technically also a parameter).
7. The type of the function's parameter. This is a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types), which describes a function that takes a single `T` parameter, and returns a `Boolean`. This can be a reference to a regular function that has this signature, but the expectation with collection functions such as this is that most of the time this will be a [lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions).
8. The return type of the function.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I needed. The only thing I'm confused about now is `3.` (the first `<T>`). Can you give a practical example of using that type parameter? I completely understand the 2nd `<T>` - it's the type of `Iterable` passed through (e.g. `Int`) - but I'm not sure about the first `<T>`.

Comment: You need to declare any type parameters that you'll use in your function after the `fun` keyword, otherwise writing down `T` in `Iterable<T>` would refer to a real type literally named `T`. This is how you let the compiler know that the `T` you're using is a generic parameter.

Comment: The second `<T>` is exactly the practical example use of the first `<T>`, along with `(T) -> Boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

inline - Take the body of this function and put it where it is being called when compiled instead of calling a function.

fun - function declaration

- generic type called T

Iterable - class we are adding an extension function too. (If it is not `inline` read static function)

all - name of the function

predicate - parameter named predicate

: (T) -> Boolean - Lambda Type takes a T as a parameter and returns a Boolean. Usually in the form `{ it == foo }`

: Boolean - Returns a Boolean