# what is the correct use of inline function in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need a real life example when we can use this. I have gone through this link [(https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) but not able to find a good example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when to use an inline function in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471284/when-to-use-an-inline-function-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So let's say we have a higher-order function, which takes another function as a parameter

```
fun doSomething(block: () -> Unit){

}
```

the Kotlin compiler will convert this to equivalent Java code which would be,

```
void doSomething( new Function(){

  void invoke(){
      // the code which you passed in the functional parameter
   }

})
```

The Kotlin compiler creates an Anonymous Inner Class for the functional parameter you passed and when you call this passed functional parameter the compiler internally calls this `invoke()` method.

As a result, all functional parameter results in extra object creation and function call which is a performance and memory overhead.

We can avoid this overhead by introducing the `inline` modifier. When added to a function the function call is skipped and the function code is added at the call site instead.

So let's say we have a simple testing function,

```
inline fun testing(block : () -> Unit){ 

   println("Inside the testing block")
   block()
   someOtherRandomFunction()

}
```

and we call this testing function from the main function, like this

```
fun main(){

   testing{
           println("Passed from the main function")     
   }

}
```

When the above main function gets compiled, it would look like

```
fun main(){

   println("Inside the testing block")
   println("Passed from the main function")
   someOtherRandomFunction()

}
```

As if no testing function ever existed, all the code body from the testing function is simply copy-pasted inside the main function body.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
inline fun TextView.onTextChanged(crossinline onTextChangeListener: (String) -> Unit) {
     addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
         override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
              onTextChangeListener(editable.toString())
         }

         ... 
     ) 
}
```

So if you're passing a lambda but you don't want to underneath create an anonymous inner class but rather inline the lambda into the call, then you can use `inline`. If you need to invoke this lambda inside another anonymous object or lambda, you can use `crossinline`.