# What is a good use case for Kotlin function inlining?

Tags: function, kotlin, inline, inlining

I was recently learning about Kotlin inline functions.  I thought the below function, twipsToPixels, seemed like a good use-case for that, but IntelliJ gives me a warning saying there's an "expected performance impact".  I would've thought the opposite would be true here?  This makes me think I'm missing something deeper.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
private inline fun twipsToPixels(value: Int) = (value * SCREEN_RESOLUTION / TWIPS_CONVERSION).roundToInt()

private fun screenBoxInPixels(screenBox: ScreenBox): ScreenBox {
  val left = twipsToPixels(screenBox.position.left)
  val top = twipsToPixels(screenBox.position.top)
  val width = twipsToPixels(screenBox.size.width)
  val height = twipsToPixels(screenBox.size.height)
  return ScreenBox(Position(left, top), Size(width, height))
}
```

Comment: Mainly `reified` parameters are the reason for inlining. A good JVM will inline methods anyway if that's efficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471284/when-to-use-an-inline-function-in-kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when to use an inline function in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471284/when-to-use-an-inline-function-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

> but IntelliJ gives me a warning saying there's an "expected performance impact"

You misread it; it says this impact is insignificant, that is, probably too small to bother. The second part of the message is

> Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types

mainly because it allows avoiding creating function objects for these parameters in the first place.