# kotlin - probably redundant branching in suspending simple method call chain

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
package basic

import kotlin.concurrent.thread
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

internal suspend fun bar() {
    suspendCoroutine {
        thread {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            it.resume(Unit)
        }
    }
}



package basic

class SimpleCoroutine {
    private suspend fun foo() {
        bar()
    }
}
```

*Bytecode for above*

```
// ================basic/SimpleCoroutine.class =================
// class version 52.0 (52)
// access flags 0x31
public final class basic/SimpleCoroutine {


  // access flags 0x12
  // signature (Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation<-Lkotlin/Unit;>;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  // declaration:  foo(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit>)
  private final foo(Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
   L0
    LINENUMBER 5 L0
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESTATIC basic/BarKt.bar (Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    DUP
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/coroutines/intrinsics/IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    IF_ACMPNE L1
    ARETURN
   L1
    POP
   L2
    LINENUMBER 6 L2
    GETSTATIC kotlin/Unit.INSTANCE : Lkotlin/Unit;
    ARETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lbasic/SimpleCoroutine; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE $completion Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation; L0 L3 1
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lbasic/SimpleCoroutine; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  @Lkotlin/Metadata;(mv={1, 7, 0}, k=1, d1={"\u0000\u0014\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\u0008\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0002\u0008\u0002\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\u0011\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004H\u0082@\u00f8\u0001\u0000\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0005\u0082\u0002\u0004\n\u0002\u0008\u0019\u00a8\u0006\u0006"}, d2={"Lbasic/SimpleCoroutine;", "", "()V", "foo", "", "(Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;", "KotlinSuspendingFunctions"})
  // compiled from: SimpleCoroutine.kt
}


// ================META-INF/KotlinSuspendingFunctions.kotlin_module =================
"*
```

*Decompiled Java code*

```
package basic;

import kotlin.Metadata;
import kotlin.Unit;
import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation;
import kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.IntrinsicsKt;

public final class SimpleCoroutine {
   private final Object foo(Continuation $completion) {
      Object var10000 = BarKt.bar($completion);
      return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

I am not sure whether to call it unnecessary or not, because I am not sure if there is a valid reason behind having

**Label 1**

```
Object var10000 = BarKt.bar($completion);
return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
```

The original method is calling a suspend method/function, the corresponding byte code should look like

```
BarKt.bar($completion);
```

**WHY?**

if you see **Label 1**, it is doing a check and returning value, but that check seems to be meaning less, since it returns the same value that it received from the call, If no manipulation or conditional return is required then why to have this overhead?

***Note that if you change the return type to `String` then it would make plain and simple, the special behavior is for `Unit` return type***

Comment: It seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: FYI, you're starting your thread twice, which is not allowed. The `thread { }` function automatically starts the thread unless you tell it not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is redundant, which I just confirmed with some snippet code,

***But why?***

I did a bit of digging into it with following sample snippet,

```
package basic

class SimpleCoroutine {
    private suspend fun foo(): String {
        return bar()
    }

    private suspend fun foo1(): Any {
        return bar1()
    }

    private suspend fun foo2(): RandomSingleton {
        return bar2()
    }

    private suspend fun foo3() {
        return bar3()
    }
}
```

*The generated code is as follows*

```
public final class SimpleCoroutine {
   private final Object foo(Continuation $completion) {
      return BarKt.bar($completion);
   }

   private final Object foo1(Continuation $completion) {
      return BarKt.bar1($completion);
   }

   private final Object foo2(Continuation $completion) {
      return BarKt.bar2($completion);
   }

   private final Object foo3(Continuation $completion) {
      Object var10000 = BarKt.bar3($completion);
      return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

In all function the generated code is almost identical to the source code except for the foo3, where the return type is `kotlin.Unit` which is a singleton from kotlin standard library. Now we all know that the default return type is `Unit` in kotlin.

So to clear the air I also made one singleton object of my own which I used to check with `foo2()` however there no redundant check is applied.

The only conclusion I can reach is that the compiler is doing guess work;

```
Object var10000 = BarKt.bar($completion);
return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
```

From the above snippet from your question,

```
var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
```

The tricky part is that it is not sure whether the value returned by `BarKt.bar($completion);` will be `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED | kotlin.Unit`, it seems that compiler some how not sure for the right part will always `kotlin.Unit`, which is why it explicitly returns `Unit.INSTANCE`.

Answer (score 1):

If `BarKt.bar()` returns `IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()` then we want `foo()` to also return `IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED()` so it can report on up the chain that we are suspended. If `BarKt.bar()` returns something else (which will be `Unit.INSTANCE`), then we know it is finished so we no longer need to suspend and can therefore return our final value of `Unit.INSTANCE` from `foo()`.

Theoretically, we could optimize this code and skip the check because both functions return `Unit.INSTANCE`. So to generalize it, the Kotlin compiler could skip the check when the return type of both the caller and the callee is `Unit.INSTANCE`, since it is known to be an immutable singleton.

However, this is a simple reference equality check and JIT runtimes may effectively eliminate it anyway. In comparison to all the continuation manipulation going on as part of this machine, the equality check is rather trivial. So, it's not much, if any, of an optimization.

And it's not a common case in practice. Suspend functions that return `Unit` are somewhat rare (aside from `delay()` and `join()`), and the "optimization" can only be done for a suspend function that is at the very tail end of the current function.

So maybe the authors of the compiler decided it's not worth the extra complexity. I'm just speculating.

Comment: if it returns X then check if it is X then return X, Does it make sense? To me, it does not make sense to add a check and then return the same thing. the other part is returning `Unit` which is again the same thing that would be returned by the `bar()`

Comment: Anyway the return type of the `bar()` function is a union of COROUTINE_SUSPENDED and Unit, at any point in time it will return either of two, Then putting a condition and returning the same values again does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @rahat Yes, I understand it’s unnecessary logically. That’s what my second paragraph explains. The rest of my answer explains why they probably didn’t simplify the bytecode for this—it would make the compiler code more complicated for questionable gains.